# Is it possible to show Google Form responses as a Google Sheet accessible to all respondents?

Tags: google-forms

Trying to use an exisiting contact sign up Google form and have the responses display in a google sheet or similar type table accessible to all respondents. I've looked for an add-on for this and could not find one. I'm new to coding and not sure if it is possible to code for this on forms or how to start.